# I want my bootstrap carousel to slide when keyboard left and right arrows are pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a carousel with images inside a modal window. I want the images to slide back and forth when I press the left/right arrow keys on the keyboard. According to the bootstrap carousel documentation the data-keyboard  attribute default value is true, but nothing happens when I press the arrow keys! So I tried putting the attribute in the code and still nothing happens when I press left/right arrow keys.

Question - Should the pics slide back and forth automatically with a left/right keyboard press? If yes, then I have something messed up, if no, do I need some JS carousel event captured and then slide manually with js/jquery?

Here is my code!

```html
<div class="modal" id="profileImageModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">@*<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>*@<i class="fa fa-flag-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Image Removal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center;">
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" data-interval="false" data-keyboard="true" class="carousel slide">
          <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            @for (int i = 0; i
            < Model.YogaProfileImages.Count(); i++) { var profileImageId=@ Model.YogaProfileImages.ElementAt(i).YogaProfileImageId; <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="@i" class="@(ViewBag.SelectedImageId == profileImageId ? "
            active " : " ")">
              </li>
              }
          </ol>

          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            @for (int i = 0; i
            < Model.YogaProfileImages.Count(); i++) { var profileImageId=@ Model.YogaProfileImages.ElementAt(i).YogaProfileImageId; <div id=@profileImageId class="item @(ViewBag.SelectedImageId == profileImageId ? " active " : " ")"
            data-profileId="@Model.Id">
              <img style="display: block; margin: auto; border-radius: 6px;" src="data:image/jpg;base64, @(Html.Raw(Convert.ToBase64String(Model.YogaProfileImages.ElementAt(i).CroppedImage)))" alt="profile image">
          </div>
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align: center; border-top: none;">
      <input id="deleteModalWarningClose" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" value="Close" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Please make your code example work to get a better answer. But upto now it seems like this could help you:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 37) {
       // Previous
       $(".carousel-control.left").click();
       return false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode === 39) {
       // Next
       $(".carousel-control.right").click();
       return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: so the default behavior of a bootstrap carousel doesn't slide the images to the left and right when the arrows are pressed!??? You would think it would, by default

Comment: also this uses the flippers! I removed my flippers from the code.

Comment: It is not about, what exactly you are doing, when you triggered the right keypress. It's about how to get there ;) Have a closer look at the documentation: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/#carouselprev

You can easily match the code for your situation by removing the .click() code and replace it by something like .carousel('prev'), as shown in the linked documentation, under "Methods" :)

Comment: I applied to smoothproducts() slider It's working fine , my issue is that if there is no image left to slide it still highting right button while fade left button , while this should be blur right button and hightlight left button

Comment: for key event, it is recommended to use keyup instead, because if one holds the key down for a while, only when releases the event is fired. Martin P. gives the clue, the best way to move carousel is using $('.carousel').carousel('prev'); and $('.carousel').carousel('next');

Answer (score 0):

I would use some jquery event listenner such as .on('keyup', somefunction()) see documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) and in this function if right arrow was pressed I would increment an index that would "lead" to the image I would want my carousel to show. The same thing applies to left arrow being pressed but in this situation I would decrease the index. If I didn't get your problem correctly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked =>

```js
<script>
    $(".carousel").carousel({
        interval: 6000,
        keyboard: true
    });
</script>
```

But it only worked when i have added left & right control arrows on the image and pressed one of the arrows at least once. After that i could use the left and right arrows on the keyboard to slide the images.